# Updating two Android Notification simultaneously at the same time

Tags: java, android, notifications

I am having a situation in which I need to update two notifications simultaneously. I have a service which plays audio and while playing the audio I used to show a notification of the player. Also in another activity I have a download method which downloads some audio and during download I need to show a notification of the download progress. So in some case if both the above thing is occuring then I need to show two different notifications together both having different Notification ID and different Notification Channel.

During download its progress changes every seconds and therefore the download notification get updated every seconds. And during this if anyone changes the audio source then the player notification is required to update and this cause my problem, the player notification doesn't get updated and I saw this happen only when the download notification is getting updated otherwise when there is no download notification to be updated then everything works fine.

I am using AsyncTask to download and showing notification using

```
  @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context.get(), NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_DOWNLOADING_ID)
                .setProgress(100, 0, true)
                .setContentTitle(context.get().getString(R.string.downloading) + "-" + name)
                .setContentText("0%")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.notification)
                .setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_DOWNLOADING_ID)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .addAction(0, context.get().getResources().getString(R.string.cancel), cancelIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true);


        NotificationChannel mChannel;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = "Download Notification";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
            mChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_DOWNLOADING_ID, name, importance);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(102, notificationBuilder.build());


 }

  @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
           //all the downloading stuff
           publishProgress(progress_value);
           ....
        }

  @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        notificationBuilder.setContentText(progress[0] + "%");
        notificationBuilder.setProgress(100, progress[0], false);
        //notification getting update every seconds due to continuous change in progress
        notificationManager.notify(102, notificationBuilder.build());


    }
```

Now in my player service -

```
     notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.app_icon2))
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.notification)
                .setTicker(Constant.arrayList_play.get(Constant.playPos).getMp3Name())
                .setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true);

      NotificationChannel mChannel;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = "Music Playback";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
            mChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }
      mNotificationManager.notify(101, notification.build());
```

I have tried changing the progress update duration by increasing the interval then the player notification works properly when the later's notification is not getting update.

Can anyone please help me a little in this matter and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Notification IDs should be different

```
mNotificationManager.notify(Notification_ID, notification.build());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i already use different Notification IDs. I have already written in the question- both having different Notification ID and different Notification Channel.